# flickr API does not provide any results

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hi I am trying this Flickr API, where I want to display title + image, for the first 3. But it's not working.

**http://jsfiddle.net/28hEb/6/**

```
var tag = "mount";
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=" + tag + "&tagmode=all& format=json&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.items, function (index, item) {
        $("<div>").html(item.title).appendTo("#content");
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#content");
        if (index == 3) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @JasonP still not working

Comment: Still had a syntax error, and it appears you want `item.title`: http://jsfiddle.net/Bmm2q/

Comment: In jsfiddle, hit the jshint button.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
    tags: "mount",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json",
}, function (data) {
    var $content = $('#content');
    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        $("<div>").html(item.title.m).appendTo($content);
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo($content);
        if (i == 3) {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28hEb/3/)

The `}` should end *before* the callback. Hence the issue. Your browser's console should give you a hint of what the error is.

Comment: Does not support what? And your title does not tell me anything of that sort

Comment: Yes i do.. Check the fiddle.